# CQ5 ExtJs widgets

Tags: extjs, aem

I am new to Adobe CQ5 version 5.6.1 and trying to learn widget creation using ExtJs, so I am doing a few examples. All I am trying to do here is show an alert box on click of a button but not getting it. Here is the code.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    helpPath="en/cq/current/wcm/default_components.html#Title"
    title="Title Component"
    xtype="panel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <webcastAtAGlanceTitle
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            fieldLabel="Title"
            maxLength="{Long}25"
            name="./webcastAtAGlanceTitle"
            xtype="textfield"/>
        <selection
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            defaultValue="pageProp"
            fieldLabel="Configuration Options"
            name="./selection"
            type="radio"
            xtype="selection">
            <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <pageProp
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    text="Page Properties"
                    value="pageProp"/>
                <RTE
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    text="RTE"
                    value="RTE"/>
            </options>
        </selection>
       <testbutton
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        autoWidth="{Boolean}true"
        fieldLabel="test button"
        text="Ok"
        xtype="button">
        <listener
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            click="function(){alert(&quot;Hello World&quot;,&quot;All set!!!&quot;);}"/>
    </testbutton>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

I am sure this is pretty simple to implement. Appreciate the inputs.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't need a listener at all. Alternatively, you can use the `handler` property to specify the function that needs to be called when the button is clicked.

```
<testbutton
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    autoWidth="{Boolean}true"
    fieldLabel="test button"
    text="Ok"
    xtype="button"
    handler="function(b, e){alert('Hello!!');}" />
```

The b and e are the button and event objects respectively, that are passed to the handler. For further reference check [this Button API](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/?class=CQ.Ext.Button).

And for the listener part, the node name has to be `listeners` instead of listener. That should work.

```
<testbutton
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    autoWidth="{Boolean}true"
    fieldLabel="test button"
    text="Ok"
    xtype="button">
    <listeners
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        click="function(){alert(&quot;Hello World&quot;,&quot;All set!!!&quot;);}"/>
</testbutton>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It certainly worked. But just curious, how can I achieve the same using listener. This is just a beginner example, so to learn further I will have to use listener at some point.

Comment: Well. I am not sure why, but the listener in your question does work for me. Can you please post the complete dialog structure in your question, so that i can check if there is some other issue.

Comment: Updated the answer. Kindly check now